# Writing Dynamic MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a `division_Type` table

```
Division_ID || Division_Area    || Parent_ID

     1       Central_Level        
     2        Provincial            1   // Provinvial Parent_ID is Central_level
     3        District              2   // District Parent_ID is Provincial
     4          MOH                 3
     5          PHI                 4
```

And I have a `Division_Details` Table

```
Division_Det_ID || Div_Name  || Division_Type_ID || Parent_ID

        1          Western         2                
        2          Eastern         2                
        3          Colombo         3                  1    //Colombo Parent ID is Western ID
        4          Nugegoda        4                  3    //Nugegoda Parent_ID is Colombo ID
        5          Udahamulla      5                  4
        6          Gampaha         5                  4
        7          Negambo         5                  2
```

Hi I have two tables named `Division_Details` and `division_Type`. `Division_ID` is the foreign key of `Division_Type_ID`. In the Example `Division_Details` Table `Parent_ID` is the `Parent ID(Division where the lower level division belongs to)` of Each Division. I may need to find the `PHI areas` belongs to `Colombo district`. That's why I told this is a dynamic query. 
Please someone give even a doc for me to refer. As I haven't any idea about this thing.

I'm getting the `ID(Division_Det_ID)` of Western. What I need to find out is what is the PHI area of Western. 
Well I need to write a dynamic query. I have no any idea to to go this more further. As u can see in the `Division_Details` table `Udahamulla, Negambo, Gampaha` are `PHI areas`. Among them `Udahamulla` and `Gampaha` are `PHI areas` of `Western`. So I need to get the `IDs` of these `PHI areas` as it belongs to the `Western` Province.

Edited:

If I select PHI in the first text box, result in the second select box should be Udahamulla, Gampaha, Nugambo. In the sorting text box when Western is selected only Udahamulla and Gampaha should be shown. Since Negambo is in Eastern Province.

Comment: "Parent" pointers are a crappy way of representing multi-level structures like trees in SQL...precisely because one query can't get a whole subtree at once.  Google "nested sets" for a better representation.

Comment: Would you please give us you expected output please?

Comment: Nested sets is the way to go here.

Comment: Details miss what the requirement is exactly you should better give some sample output

Comment: Hello everyone I really appreciate your help. I edited my question back. It is now clear to your all. Please let me know the issues. If anyone knows can please give me an example?